# neo4j trying to do UNION but I still see stuff that's outside of the range

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql, match, union

``Hi! I have a database of people who watch and like movies. Total of 5 people in which the friend relationshio goes like this: a>b>c>d>e. Im trying to get all the movies that they watched and liked from person a up to person d. I got it to work with this query but there were a lot of duplicates:

```
MATCH(p:Person{name:'Joe'})-[:Friend*1..3]->(f) 
MATCH(m:Movie)<-[:Watched]-(f) 
MATCH(ml:Movie)<-[:Liked]-(f) 
MATCH (mg:Movie)<-[:Watched]-(p) 
MATCH (mgl:Movie)<-[:Liked]-(p) 
RETURN m,ml,mg,mgl
```

I tried to narrow it down with UNION but I still see a movie which only person e saw and liked:

```
MATCH(p:Person{name:'Joe'})-[:Friend*..3]->(f)
MATCH(m:Movie)<-[:Watched]-(f)
RETURN m
UNION 
MATCH(m:Movie)<-[:Liked]-(f)
RETURN m
UNION
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:Watched]-(p) 
RETURN m 
UNION 
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:Liked]-(p) 
RETURN m
```

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

You need:
- expand the match pattern to the left and right
- then to put the films in the list
- unwind it
- and remove duplicates

```
MATCH (mp:Movie)<-[:Watched|Liked]-(p:Person{name:'Joe'})
      -[:Friend*1..3]->
      (f:Person)-[:Watched|Liked]->(mf:Movie)
WITH collect(DISTINCT mp) + collect(DISTINCT mf) AS movies
UNWIND movies AS movie
RETURN DISTINCT movie
```

Comment: That didnt work but it did help me to get to my answer:
`MATCH(p:Person{name:'Joe'})-[:Friend*1..3]->(f) MATCH(m:Movie)<-[:Watched]-(f) MATCH(ml:Movie)<-[:Liked]-(f) MATCH (mg:Movie)<-[:Watched]-(p) MATCH (mgl:Movie)<-[:Liked]-(p) WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT m) + COLLECT(DISTINCT ml) + COLLECT(DISTINCT mg) + COLLECT(DISTINCT mgl) AS movies UNWIND movies AS movie RETURN DISTINCT movie`
So thanks! =)